# The last header file error: C2065: 'xxx' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, qt, include

Today，I encounter a very very strange problem.That's my IDE always can not identify the last class I include last.I am using Qt Creator.My includes as follow:

```
#include "realtimemonitor.h"
#include "ui_realtimemonitor.h"

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "forkliftinfo.h"
#include <thread>
#include "goodsitem.h"
#include "goodslocationitem.h"
#include "forkliftitem.h"
#include "chargingstationitem.h"
```

At this time, IDE complain "**ChargingStationItem** undeclared identifier".
If I swap **forkliftitem.h** with **chargingstationitem.h**,IDE will compain "**ForkliftItem** undeclared identifier".My **forkliftitem.h** as follow:

```
//forkliftitem.h
#ifndef CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H
#define CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class ForkliftItem : public QGraphicsItem  { public:
    ForkliftItem();
    };

#endif // CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H
```

And chargingstationitem.h:

```
//chargingstationitem.h
#ifndef CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H
#define CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H
#include <QGraphicsItem> 

class ChargingStationItem : public QGraphicsItem  { public:
    ChargingStationItem();
    };

#endif // CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: asked Nov 14 '16 at 16:08 by Crawl.W
This is not a nonsense question, which is just less common. Whether it's carelessness or an editor bug, this question helps at these times. The adopted answer was upvote 3 times that enough to show his contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both files you have include guards with the same name - CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H. So, in first file, it defines CHARGINGSTATIONITEM_H and in second file just ignores all content.